# Every time I hit the submit button the values all go back to 0 in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using the following code, every time I hit the submit button the values all go back to 0

```
        If txtBedrooms.Text = String.Empty Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a bedroom 0 or greater")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf Not IsNumeric(txtBedrooms.Text) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a bedroom 0 or greater")
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf txtBedrooms.Text < 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a bedroom 0 or greater")
            Exit Sub
        Else
            txtBedrooms.Text = bedrooms.ToString
        End If
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you post some more code, including the submit button code?

Comment: Which values - txtBedrooms.Text and bedrooms? Is this Winforms? Straight VB or VB.NET? Is the code above in the OnClick handler of the button in the title? More information please.

Comment: @IanNelson: will be WinForms in VB.Net as `MessageBox.Show` is used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set a value for bedrooms? It is not in the code you submitted?

I "think" you are trying to set bedrooms to the value of txtBedrooms.
If that is the case, the assignment is the wrong way round and needs switching to

```
bedrooms = Convert.ToInt32(txtBedrooms.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
    txtBedrooms.Text = bedrooms.ToString
```

If anything is entered into the text box you'll fall through to this line and as you're wanting to set the value of bedrooms to what has been entered into the text box it will still be zero and you'll overwrite the text box with 0.